# Word meaning "expressing innocous concept with offensive near-homonym"

Tags: single-word-requests

Years ago, an Internet NNTP poster's signature read in part "a 
niggardly lover".

Of course, "niggardly" just means "stingy", so there was nothing 
literally offensive in his signature.

However, I believe he chose this phrasing (instead of "stingy lover" 
or "miserly lover") specifically to provoke and annoy people.

What word embodies this concept? Using an intentionally 
offensive-sounding phrase to express an otherwise inoffensive concept?

Would this be the opposite of bowdlerization?

Answer (score 4):

It is an interesting approach to baiting people.  Bowdlerization and other forms of censorship could be considered "opposites" to this.  I tend to prefer the contrast with the idea of [**minced oaths**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath):

> A **minced oath** (also pseudo-profanity) is an expression based on a profanity or a taboo term that has been altered to reduce the objectionable characteristics. ... The most common methods of forming a minced oath are rhyme and alliteration.

Meanwhile it shares many similarities with [**eggcorn**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn):

> An **eggcorn** is an idiosyncratic substitution of a word or phrase for a word or words that sound similar or identical in the speaker's dialect. The new phrase introduces a meaning that is different from the original, but plausible in the same context, such as "old-timers' disease" for "Alzheimer's disease". ... Eggcorns often involve replacing an unfamiliar, archaic, or obscure word with a more common or modern word

The user seems to be attempting to create a malicious eggcorn in the reader's mind, replacing an archaic term with a more modern (and offensive) one.  Indeed, seeing as the original word was primarily negative, a racial slur could introduce a meaning "different from the original, but plausible in the same context."

There have been numerous public controversies over this particular word pair.  ([*Controversies about the word "niggardly"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_about_the_word_%22niggardly%22))

Ultimately, though, I think the word to describe this behavior best might just be "**trolling**."

Answer (score 4):

If it is indeed deliberate, OP's example is a form of [asteism](http://thinkexist.com/dictionary/meaning/asteism/) *(genteel irony; a polite and ingenious manner of deriding another)*. Depending on one's preconceptions, it may be considered *subversive, provocative,* or *couched language*.

It's not *dys-/mal-/cacophemism*, because all of those imply that the actual words used are inherently offensive. I'm well aware that there have even been lawsuits in America arising from the word *niggardly* - but even where the complainants won their case (most didn't), no lawyers ever argued that the actual word was offensive.

It's almost the direct opposite of a *minced oath*, since the intention there is to *avoid* giving offense. So much so that one hears [berk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/berk) *(slang: fool)* used in polite society by people who may actually be giving offense without knowing what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

This would, I believe, come under ["dysphemism":](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism)

> In language, dysphemism (from the Greek dys δύς "mis-" and pheme φήμη "reputation"), **malphemism** (in Latin malus "bad"), and **cacophemism** (in Greek kakos κακός "bad") refer to the usage of an intentionally harsh word or expression instead of a polite one.

If this was written to make it intentionally offensive, it would have been a ["cacophemism":](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism#Related_terms)

> While "dysphemism" or "malphemism" may be either offensive or merely humorously deprecating, "cacophemism" is usually deliberately offensive